# Object has no attribute - Variable name shared between classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object, attributes

I need to assign a new account to a `SalesRep` while also updating my `Account`'s class to have Leslie as it's sales rep.

I recieve the error:

```
'str' object has no attribute 'set_sales_rep'
```

When I test the following lines:

```
rep_1 = SalesRep('Leslie', 'Knope', ['acct1', 'acct2', 'acct3'])
print(rep_1.add_account('acct4'))
```

`SalesRep` class:

```
class SalesRep(object):

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, accounts=None):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self._accounts = []

        if accounts:
            self._accounts.extend(accounts)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{self.first_name} {self.last_name}".format(self=self)

    def get_accounts(self):
        return self._accounts

    def add_account(self, account):
        self._accounts.append(account)
        account.set_sales_rep(self)
```

`Account` class:

```
class Account(object):

    def __init__(self, name, sales_rep=None, segments=None):
        self.name = name
        self._sales_rep = sales_rep
        self._segments = []

        if segments:
            self._segments.extend(segments)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{self.name}".format(self=self)

    def get_sales_rep(self):
        return self._sales_rep

    def set_sales_rep(self, sales_rep):
        self._sales_rep = sales_rep
```

All I'm trying to do is test that add_account in the `SalesRep` class is working, I have 'set_sales_rep' defined in the `Account` class. I'm unsure if the error is that I'm relating 'set_sales_rep' incorrectly between the classes or my `print()` function call at the top is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rep_1 = SalesRep('Leslie', 'Knope', ['acct1', 'acct2', 'acct3'])
print(rep_1.add_account('acct4'))
```

You are passing a string to add_account instead of an account object.

Create an account object, `acc = Account(name="acc4")`, and then pass it to add_account, `rep_1.add_account(acc)`.

Comment: Note that after fixing this, the following call to `print()` will display `None` because the `SalesRep.add_account()` method doesn't return anything...